# Флаг -short в тестах Go

Tags: golang, юнит-тесты

Читая доку по Go, я наткнулся на

```
func TestTimeConsuming(t *testing.T) {
    if testing.Short() {
        t.Skip("skipping test in short mode.")
    }
    ...
}
```

Я поймал себя на мысли, что не понимаю, зачем нужно `testing.Short()`. Могли бы Вы привести пример, когда эта операция жизненно необходима?

[Источник](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Жизненной" необходимости в небольших (меньше 50 000 строк кода) проектах нет. Необходимость появляется тогда, когда проект становится большим, а количество необходимых к проверке условий растёт. Например, помимо юнит-тестов, появляются интеграционные тесты.

Если правильно расположить условия по `testing.Short()`, в таких проектах можно разделить тесты на "короткие" и "полные". Пока разработчик работает над своей задачей, он запускает "короткие" тесты, которые пробегают за несколько секунд. Как только задача готова, он запускает "полные" тесты, проходящие несколько минут, чтобы перед коммитом убедиться, что не поломалось ничего, что не относится напрямую к задаче.

Comment: Т.е. список коротких тестов может меняться в зависимости от задачи? Если я работаю, например, над реализацией графового алгоритма, то короткими будут все те тесты, которые не относятся к графовому алгоритму? В таком случае уместно делать короткими тесты, относящиеся к тому коду, который уже более или менее протестирован?

Comment: @hedgehogues Нет. У вас есть тесты. Некоторые из них отрабатывают медленно. Другие - быстро. Медленные можно закрывать условием по `testing.Short()`.